# Linux Mint 19.3 Bluetooth showing multiple IDs

Tags: linux-mint, bluetooth

I'm a linux newbie, and my computer started showing up under two different bluetooth names for no apparent reason

[image]

I assigned the LINUX suffix, and it worked fine for a few days, then the computer switched to the #2 suffix. Now when I connect devices, they connect to the LINUX name. For example, I connect speakers, and they show that they're connected to the LINUX suffix, but don't actually work on my computer or register as being connected.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Update:

My bluetooth device seems to be installed twice:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I partially solved this with `sudo apt-get install blueman`

Then in the bluetooth manager, I forgot all bluetooth from the old "adapter." It's still there for whatever reason, but no longer interferes with the correct adapter.